# hadoop streaming failing with simple mapping & reduce job (with nltk code) in hadoop 1.0.0

Tags: hadoop

my excution code and output from that

```
[hduser@Janardhan hadoop]$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.0.jar -file /home/hduser/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file /home/hduser/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /user/hduser/input.txt -output /home/hduser/outpututttt


 Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

    packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/mapper.py, /home/hduser/reducer.py, /app/hadoop/tmp/hadoop-unjar2185859252991058106/] [] /tmp/streamjob2973484922110272968.jar tmpDir=null
    12/05/03 20:36:02 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    12/05/03 20:36:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local]
    12/05/03 20:36:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201205032014_0003
    12/05/03 20:36:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
    12/05/03 20:36:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:54311 -kill job_201205032014_0003
    12/05/03 20:36:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201205032014_0003
    12/05/03 20:36:04 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
    12/05/03 20:36:21 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
    12/05/03 20:36:24 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
    12/05/03 20:37:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
    12/05/03 20:37:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
    12/05/03 20:37:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=localhost:54311 -kill job_201205032014_0003
    12/05/03 20:37:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost.localdomain:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201205032014_0003
    12/05/03 20:37:00 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201205032014_0003_m_000000
    12/05/03 20:37:00 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
    Streaming Job Failed!
```

Here's the error I get from the job tracker:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

It works locally with this code:

```
 [hduser@Janardhan ~]$ cat input.txt | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py 
('be', 'VB')    1
('ceremony', 'NN')  1
('first', 'JJ')     2
('for', 'IN')   2
('hi', 'NN')    1
('place', 'NN')     1
('the', 'DT')   2
('welcome', 'VBD')  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to debug by inspecting the stderr logs on the data node where the map and reduce tasks failed.  These usually shed a lot of light when a job that runs locally fails on the cluster.

You should be able to access the logs through the hadoop cluster's jobtracker web interface, at, typically at http://master.node.ip.address:50030/jobtracker.jsp.  Your job should show up under "failed job".  Click on the job ID, then on a map or reduce task in the "failed" column, and you should see the logs.

Note that if mapper.py and reducer.py are not executable (first line #!/usr/bin/python, file attributes set correctly), you may need to change the arguments to "-mapper 'python mapper.py'", etc.